# handling SIGSEGV, to know the access size

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am writing c program to handle SIGSEGV.
Beside the address which caused the signal, I also want to know the size, the program tried to access (16 bits v.s. 32 bits v.s 64 bits).

I disassembled the codes in gdb and found that for different size, they used different assembly commands, "movb" (uint8) "movw" (uint16) "movl" (uint32) "movq" (uint64), as shown below.

In the handler of SIGSEGV, is there a way for us to find how many bits/bytes the program tried to access?
(assume I am working on x86-64 and linux)

```
void *buffer;

...

mprotect(buffer, pagesize, PROT_NONE);

uint8 *pu8 = (uint8*)buffer;
pu8[0]=1;  // movb

uint16 *pu16 = (uint16*)buffer;
pu16[0]=1;  // movw

uint32 *pu32 = (uint32*)buffer;
pu32[0]=1;  // movl

uint64 *pu64 = (uint64*)buffer;
pu64[0]=1;  // movq
```

Comment: If you can get the address where the signal happened, you can read the instruction and figure out how much it's trying to access from that.

Comment: I wouldn't try to "handle" SIGSEGV. Just run the offending program through a debugger and fix it.

Comment: I am not debugging a software. I am trying to build a virtualization solution. The problem of reading instruction is that it is still hard to distinguish 32-bit write from 64-bit write (both using "mov" if rhs is a variable in C). I just wonder if there is a known approach to this problem.